# Django not accepting request from client using bearer token from react native

Tags: javascript, django, react-native, redux, axios

I have been stuck on this for a couple days. If I pass the bearer token as hard coded it works but if I use props or a variable it gets rejected.. I am not too sure what is wrong. I also added a check in the component before to make sure the jwt is there.

```
 import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
} from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

var axios = require("axios");

const FriendsList = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    var config = {
      method: "get",
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/getuserinfo/",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${props.jwt}`,
      },
    };
    const fetchD = async () => {
      const res = await axios(config).then(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      });
      res();
    };
    fetchD();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>FriendList</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default FriendsList;
```

Here is the component before the above, I can login but when I pass the bearer token to the server I get back a 400 response not authorized
:0

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
} from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { accessCookie, storeUserInfo } from "../fetchFunctions/cookie";
import { UserInfo } from "../fetchFunctions/getInfoCook";
import FriendsList from "./Components/FriendsList";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

const Working = () => {
  const jwt = useSelector((state) => state.userSignedIn.jwt);

  const username = useSelector((state) => state.userInfo.username);
  const phone_number = useSelector((state) => state.userInfo.phone_number);
  const email = useSelector((state) => state.userInfo.phone_number);
  //pass into friend component

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      {jwt !== undefined ? <FriendsList jwt={jwt} /> : <Text>Loading</Text>}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Working;
```

Comment: Can you log out the auth header you generating to make sure it's what you expect: ``console.log(`Bearer ${props.jwt}`)``? Do you need to add `props.jwt` to the dependency array for your `useEffect` hook, `props.jwt` may not be correct the first time it's rendered?

Comment: @IainShelvington lol... yup did not console log that.. it had inner quotations. thank you lol... i tried like five different fetch modules.

Answer (score 0):

yurp it is the weirdness of the bearer token with inner quotes.

```
  const bearer = `Bearer ${action.payload.jwt}`;
  const processedB = bearer.replace(/\"/g, "");
```

thanks Iain Shelvington